# SBT native packager does not copy file to Docker image

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have an Akka SBT project. It consists of multiple SBT submodules:

- **common** contains `resources/logback-prod.xml`
- **app** depends on two other submodules
- postgres

I build a docker image of the project. The only command which does not affect the image is:

```
...
dockerPackageMappings in Docker += 
   ((resourceDirectory in Compile).value / "logback-prod.xml") -> "/opt/docker/conf/logback-prod.xml"
...
```

This line of code does not copy the `logback-prod.xml` from the **common** subproject to the docker `/opt/docker/conf/` path

Instead it creates a directory with name "logback-prod.xml" by the path I mentioned above.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by this line of code:

```
mappings in Docker += (resourceDirectory in common in Compile).value / "logback-prod.xml" -> "/opt/docker/conf/logback-prod.xml",
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you get an empty directory instead of the file in Docker, it means that the source file doesn't exist. I.e. in your case it could mean that your source path is wrong. Try it with copying a file with an absolute path, and see if it gets copied in correctly.

Comment: Big thanks for the hint! I'll try it and respond with a result I get